# Ctrl + A doesn't work in Bash Terminal on OS X Lion

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app, osx-lion

In bash windows using the Terminal.app on OS X Lion, I can no longer use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> as a shortcut for going to the start of the command line. Other <kbd>ctrl</kbd> characters like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> don't work any longer either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`^A` and `^E` are commands of bash's "emacs mode". Check your bash settings with

```
set -o
```

and verify that `emacs` is set to `on`. If your bash is in vi-mode (`vi on`) then you need to use the vi shortcuts to navigate within the row (<kbd>ESC</kbd> to leave insert mode, <kbd>0</kbd> to go to the beginning and <kbd>$</kbd> to go to the end).

Comment: You should also note that to switch it back to emacs mode, do `set -o emacs`

Answer (score 6):

If you want your setting to persist between sessions, add the following to your ~/.profile.

```
set -o vi
set -o emacs
```

Of course, you should only add one of those two, depending on your preferred editing mode.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see the keyboard settings of your current theme. *Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Keyboard*.

If you don't see what you want in there try making a new theme to see if it works

Comment: I just verified, and they do seem to be working on my 10.7 box, so I think it must have something to do with the theme that you're using.

Comment: Yup. These are the most basic `bash` shortcuts and should definitely work at least in Bash. There should be no keyboard shortcuts set, actually, so *"If you don't see what you want in there"* is the default case and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Mine continues to work after the 10.7 update.  Actually works in all apps that i've tested it in...

Comment: Check your general keyboard shortcuts as well to make sure you don't have anything overwriting your ctrl shortcuts. System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: In my case it was overwritten with "Bring all windows to front". Maybe any app set that? After removing it works again like a glance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither of the existing answers solved my issue. I was able to track it down to the "Dictation" sub-menu of the Keyboard settings, where I had selected "Press Control Key Twice".

Apparently, selecting "Press Control Key Twice" as your Dictation shortcut disables the ability to type Ctrl-A in the Mac OS Terminal. Who knew!

[image: Keyboard preferences -> Dictation tab, Shortcut field, "Off" is selected]

Changing the shortcut back to "Off" allowed me to type Ctrl-A and control my `screen` sessions again.